# Mutually exclusive combinations of properties

Tags: jsonschema

Using Jsonschema draft 6, I'm trying to create a schema that conforms to the following:

1. Properties A, B1, B2, and B3 are either numbers or `null`
2. If property A is present and non-null, then properties B1, B2, and B3 must be either absent or null
3. If any of properties B1, B2, and B3 are present and non-null, then property A must be null or absent.
4. A, B1, B2, and B3 may all be absent

Examples of conforming documents:

```
{}

{"A": 1}

{"A": 1, "B2": null}

{"B1": 1}

{"B1": 1, "B2": 1, "B3": 1}

{"A": null, "B1": 1, "B2": 1, "B3": 1}
```

Examples of non-conforming documents:

```
{"A": 1, "B1": 2}

{"A": 1, "B1": null, "B2": 1}
```

I've seen some related questions that help but don't fully answer the question:

- [How to make anyOf a set of mutually exclusive properties except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330158/how-to-make-anyof-a-set-of-multually-exclusive-properties-except-one)
- [Use json-schema to require or disallow properties based on another property value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340967/use-json-schema-to-require-or-disallow-properties-based-on-another-property-valu)
- [jsonSchema attribute conditionally required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717933/jsonschema-attribute-conditionally-required)
- [How to define choice element in json schema when elements are optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048252/how-to-define-choice-element-in-json-schema-when-elements-are-optional)
- [How to define a JSON schema that requires at least one of many properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839578/how-to-define-a-json-schema-that-requires-at-least-one-of-many-properties#31841897)

Here is my current schema, which only enforces constraint #1 and #4:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "A": {"oneOf": [{"type": "null"}, {"type": "number"}],
    "B1": {"oneOf": [{"type": "null"}, {"type": "number"}],
    "B2": {"oneOf": [{"type": "null"}, {"type": "number"}],
    "B3": {"oneOf": [{"type": "null"}, {"type": "number"}]
  }
}
```

What is the right approach here? Am I asking for something unreasonable?

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "A": {"type": "number"},
        "B1": {"type": "null"},
        "B2": {"type": "null"},
        "B3": {"type": "null"}
      },
      "required": ["A"]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "A": {"type": "null"},
        "B1": {"type": ["number","null"]},
        "B2": {"type": ["number","null"]},
        "B3": {"type": ["number","null"]}
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {"required": ["B1"]},
        {"required": ["B2"]},
        {"required": ["B3"]}
      ]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "A": {"type": "null"},
        "B1": {"type": "null"},
        "B2": {"type": "null"},
        "B3": {"type": "null"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Note that B/C/D should have been B1/B2/B3 (I wrote the question incorrectly).

Comment: I think it still doesn't quite address what I originally envisioned (either A should be a number xor at least one of B1-3 should be a number), but it seems close enough to get me going. You basically have to "expand" all valid combinations.